# почему на openserver флажек желтого цвета

Tags: openserver

я не могу понять почему на openserver флажек становится желтым , затем обратно красным , сразу говорю порт менял

Comment: а в логах что? Там пишется всё, вставьте сюда текстом.

Comment: так с потолка ответ мы вряд ли найдем, пожалуйста прикрепите на свой вопрос логи `openserver`, если не ошибаюсь они лежат по пути `OSPanel/userdata/logs`